# How to build an addin for visual studio 2008

Tags: visual-studio-2008, add-in

I have a cms that exposes most its data through a somewhat kludgy mostly xml driven api. I want to build something like the LINQ to SQL Classes data context but for this cms.

How can I add something to the new item list so that I can handle its designer window?  Does that make sense?  I would be happy to clarify if anything is unclear